# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Now this is wierd, I basically calling the function "sortTiles()" twice,  the first time, it loops through, and returns a beautiful array, just as it's supposed to do. But the second time I call it, it doesn't work, and throws the error as stated in the title to a specific line: ***tiles[y][x] = tile;***.

The first time around, the returned array from "sortTiles()" is put into a global array called "solution". The second time the function is called, it will get the tiles X and Y coordinate from the solution array.

What I'm doing here is it basically scans a sliding puzzle, with the help of a html5 canvas and prnt_scrn+paste into the website. And as said, first time you do it, you take a screenshot of the solution, paste it in, and it marks out all the coordinates just fine. The second time, it throws an error :(

```
function getTile(x, y) {
    var id = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (i2 = 0; i2 < 2; i2++) {
            var data = context.getImageData(x + i * 48 + 5 - (i * 10), y + i2 * 48 + 5 - (i2 * 10), 1, 1).data;
            id += data[0] + data[1] + data[2];
        }
    }
    return id;
}

function findTile(number) {
    for (y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            if (solution[y][x] == number) {
                return [x, y];
            }
        }
    }
}

function sortTiles() {
    context.font = "20px Georgia";
    var tiles = [];
    tiles.length = 0;
    for (y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        tiles[y] = [];
        for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            var tile = getTile(108 + x * 56, 34 + y * 56);
            tiles[y][x] = tile;
            if (solution.length != 0) {
                var coordinate = findTile(tile);
                context.fillText(coordinate[0] + ", " + coordinate[1], 108 + x * 56 + 12, 34 + y * 56 + 36);
            } else {
                context.fillText(x + ", " + y, 108 + x * 56 + 12, 34 + y * 56 + 36);
            }
        }
    }
    return tiles;
}
```

Comment: `tiles` should be pushed into, not just assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `x` and `y` variables are global and are conflicting between `sortTiles` and `findTile`. Make them local using `var`.

```
function getTile(x, y) {
    var id = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (i2 = 0; i2 < 2; i2++) {
            var data = context.getImageData(x + i * 48 + 5 - (i * 10), y + i2 * 48 + 5 - (i2 * 10), 1, 1).data;
            id += data[0] + data[1] + data[2];
        }
    }
    return id;
}

function findTile(number) {
    for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            if (solution[y][x] == number) {
                return [x, y];
            }
        }
    }
}

function sortTiles() {
    context.font = "20px Georgia";
    var tiles = [];
    tiles.length = 0;
    for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        tiles[y] = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            var tile = getTile(108 + x * 56, 34 + y * 56);
            tiles[y][x] = tile;
            if (solution.length != 0) {
                var coordinate = findTile(tile);
                context.fillText(coordinate[0] + ", " + coordinate[1], 108 + x * 56 + 12, 34 + y * 56 + 36);
            } else {
                context.fillText(x + ", " + y, 108 + x * 56 + 12, 34 + y * 56 + 36);
            }
        }
    }
    return tiles;
}
```